# PayPal Bulk Payout API 'RISK_DECLINE'

Tags: paypal

Using the payouts API (in Ruby) I have some payouts that are error due to `RISK_DECLINE`:

```
name="RISK_DECLINE"
message="Transaction was declined"
information_link="https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#RISK_DECLINE
```

What does `RISK_DECLINE` mean and what can be done to fix it?

Note: the *information_link* contains returned by the API doesn't contain any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indicates that PayPal's risk/fraud engine has decided that PayPal should decline to process the payment.

It could be nearly anything, or some combination of things, that triggered the alarm. If most of your payouts are OK and only some are declined it is likely (primarily) issue(s) with the other parties' PayPal accounts, not your account.

You can contact PayPal to see if they can and are willing to give you any more specific reasons, but this isn't a technical problem and does not have a technical fix.